# Where are the lollipop OTA system upgrade files stored?

Tags: root-access, file-system, ota-update

Android devices automatically download OTA system update files and store them on your device until you install them. 
Then you get a notification that the file has been downloaded.
I do not want to update using this OTA file.
I just would like to delete the OTA file but cannot find where it is stored.
In the past they were stored in the /cache directory, but with lollipop that no longer seems to be the case.