# Where to find downloaded firmware update package?

Tags: ota-update, device-firmware

I have been using rooted Lenovo K3 Note k50a40 ( Android version 5.0 firmware S117 ROM) , system shows a notification for a firmware update I have downloaded it but I am unable to locate the package so that I can flash it manually.
I've looked at `/cache` partition(as suggested in [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32205/where-can-i-find-the-ota-update-file)  did not find any OTA file but it has an empty directory called **OTA**)

Finding - On another forum somebody suggested that the file can be found at /lenovoota folder but I can not locate the folder itself let alone the package file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the OTA update file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32205/where-can-i-find-the-ota-update-file)

Comment: Related (perhaps) : [Where are the lollipop OTA system upgrade files stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119003). Also, see [ask].

Comment: I have gone through both the questions but did not get the answer. Yeah right o should have searched first. Will keep in mind in future.

Comment: Also I have tried accessing /cache but it did not have the ota package file. /cache has a folder ota but it is empty.

Comment: can anyone help with? still searching for the downloaded ota package file. Help someone.

Comment: On another forum somebody suggested that the file can be found at /lenovoota folder but I can not locate the folder itself let alone the package file.

Comment: Ankur, posting your findings in the comment would go unnoticed here. The best way for your question to be get noticed is to update the question's body with whatever new you've got.

Answer (score 1):

I found the OTA package in following location

```
/data/data/com.lenovo.ota/app_otapackages/
```

Hope this helps you